# Identically distributed density functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Can someone give me an example of two random variables with the same probability distribution but two different density functions? I understand we can do this by changing the density function on a point. Will the value of the distribution function not change due to this. If we make the change does this become a mixed distribution?

Comment: There will be no change. Integrals are insensitive to changes on a "small enough" set.

Answer (score 1):

Try two densities of the same distribution, for example $f=\mathbf 1_{[0,1]}$ and $g=f\cdot\mathbf 1_{\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q}$.